# CPLEX ILOG OPL Optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm

The model is optimizing the costs of Machines in Cell layout design
regarding the duplication and subcontracting.
Mod Const. is,

```
forall (k in 1..Cells, i in 1..nbMachines, j in 1..nbComps)
{
    if  (U[i][j][k] == 1  && A[k][i] < ((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52)) 
         DN[i][j][k] == 1; 
    SC[i][j][k] == 0; 
    INT[i][j][k] == 0;
}
forall (k in 1..Cells, i in 1..nbMachines, j in 1..nbComps)
{
    if (V[i][j][k] == 1  && A[k][i] >= ((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52)) 
         DN[i][j][k] == 0; 
    SC[i][j][k] == 1; 
    INT[i][j][k] == 1;}
```

`U , V` are extracted in previous steps, `A, D, S` are input data.
The variables reqd. are `DN, SC and INT`.
Errors are those expressions are cannot be extracted, `U, V` are unbounded,
Please help in this regard,

Answer (score 1):

Since U and V are decision variables, you should not write:

```
if  (U[i][j][k] == 1  && A[k][i] < ((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52)) 
     DN[i][j][k] == 1;
```

Instead write:

```
((U[i][j][k] == 1)  && (A[k][i] <= -1+((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52))) 
     => (DN[i][j][k] == 1);
```